# Stopping an EC2 instance using AWS PowerShell tools from within the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, azure-devops, aws-sdk

I run a Azure DevOps pipeline that runs a PowerShell script in my instance.

The last line of the script is:

```
StopInstance -InstanceId $instanceId;
```

The instance ID is the ID of the the machine running the script.

I sometimes get an error (that is failing the pipeline):
2021-06-02T15:33:05.7903793Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.186.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.186.0\powershell.ps1'''))"'.

How can I do it without getting an error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just run `Stop-Computer -ComputerName localhost` instead of calling out to the AWS API to shutdown the computer that the powershell script is running on?

Comment: @MarkB I actually thought about it, and currently I run "shutdown -s -t 30" to let the agent job finish, but I'm curious what is the cause for that issue and if there's a better option to do it.